# Making a Adjacency Graph from a .bmp image

Tags: image-processing

I have been given an assignment of Seam carving. 
To do that I first have to convert my processed bmp image into  a graph using either adjacency list or adjacency matrix.

While creating a graph using adjacency matrix , my program hangs for about 30 secs when i try to allocate memory to adjacency matrix using malloc opearator. I like to know why  , thought my dimension of the matrix is quite large but half a minute for memory allocation is very fishy.
here my code :

```
FILE *f=fopen("ocean.bmp","rb+");
fread(&info,sizeof(unsigned char),54,f);
width=*(int *)&info[18];
height=*(int *)&info[22];
int size = height*width;
int *graph[size];
x= (height-2) * (width - 2) + 1;
for(int i=0; i<=x ; i++ ){
    graph[i]  = (int *)malloc( x * sizeof(int));
```

PS: the bmp image is converted using the energy function.

Comment: what are you trying to create?? an array of pointers..a pointer of arrays....what is the structure of graph? if each entry of graph is one image then it might take than long

Comment: Try stepping through it in the debugger.